# Ordnance Survey maps

Tags: internet-explorer, maps

In the UK, [Bing Maps](http://binged.it/1kRl1YJ) can show OS maps in the browser.  It appears that this data extends to their API, and a couple of apps have been built using the API (e.g. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/leisure-maps/f0a5f695-c8d9-40b2-814f-fbbb9d67a3da, http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/os-maps/452f262a-87c5-44c5-b28a-8718b09533cd), but these are fairly swiftly removed from the Store (I assume licencing issues, but I can't work out if this is instigated by Microsoft or OS?).

However, going to the [link above](http://binged.it/1kRl1YJ) on the mobile browser automatically opens up the Here Maps app (which doesn't have the OS Map option)
So:

- is there a way to force the browser to use the website?

and/or

- is there any other way to view OS Maps on the phone?

**WP8.1 UPDATE**

Despite [the answer below](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/5499/6035), when I click on the link in WP8.1, HERE Maps still opens, displaying the default mapping and not the OS Map - is this a difference between 8.1 dev and full, or due to something else to do with the answerer's own phone?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: There are 2 questions at the end?

Comment: Ok. 8.1 only have HERE Maps. The 8.1 Maps app uses HERE Maps.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder yes - 8 only has HERE maps too, hence my questions!

Comment: Ok. So what you want is the "graphics" frm Bing Maps?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Erm, I'm not sure what you're asking. I'm not sure if you understand my questions - perhaps they could be better worded?

Comment: I'm on 8.1 dev preview and I just tried the link you posted and I got Bing showing the OS map, not HERE app starting up.

Comment: @Rikalous Go ahead and post that as an answer :)

Comment: I know a guy who built a WP7 app that showed OS Maps - the OS asked MS to pull it as it breached license agreements.

Comment: @Rikalous I assume that's what happened with the 2 that I mentioned in my question then?

Comment: @ChrisW almost certainly. Oddly they provide free use of some of their data, so quite what piques them about map apps I don't know. Hey, it's not as if they are a 'non-Ministerial Government department and Executive Agency, reporting to Parliament' and funded by my tax pounds, er... hang on....

Comment: Using the links at the top, the two apps both say not available when marketplace opens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 8.1 dev preview and I just tried the link you posted and I got Bing showing the OS map, not HERE app starting up.